# unable to uninstall mysql broken mysql / install new mysql

Tags: mysql

I have made some shitty things to MySQL and I facing this.

I am trying to re-install MySQL. directly deleted the MySQL folder using sudo rights and tried to re-install.

the fix will be greatly appreciated

command I am running

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

following is the output I am receiving

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/a/1134184/653440

do: sudo apt edit-sources and look for anything containing mariadb like: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://ftp.nluug.nl/db/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main

comment it out by putting a # in front of it. then run

> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt purge mysql-common
>
> sudo apt install mysql-common

after that you can installed mysql-server properly via sudo apt install mysql-server

Helped me fix the issue.